# Disable the other collection view from using the method sizeForItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 2 collection views, one collection view is using sizeForItemAt for changing the size of the cell and other collection view should not be using that method.

My problem is how to disable/prevent the other collection view from using sizeForItemAt method.

Comment: So, is it your issue that both of the collection view affected by "sizeForItemAt"?

Comment: yes. my purpose for the sizeForItemAt is for changing the cell size for that specific collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aiming to recognize the which collection view to be affected by `sizeForItemAt` method, you could simply use the `===` operator for doing it.

Example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView === firstCollectionView {
        // here it should returns the desired size
        return CGSize(width: ..., height: ...)
    }

    // here it should returns the default size
    return CGSize(width: ..., height: ...)
}
```

Or (a a shorter version):

```
return collectionView === firstCollectionView ? CGSize(width: ..., height: ...) : CGSize(width: ..., height: ...)
```

Comment: @jay123456 glad that resolves your issue! I would suggest to know what is the difference between `==` and `===`. FYI, accepting an answer leads to: - gives the answerer +15 reputation points. - gives you (asker) +2 reputation points. - And the most important thing, it gives an indication for the viewers that this answer is the appropriate solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your Cell size method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    //return CGSize.init(width: self.view.frame.width / 3 - 30, height: self.view.frame.width / 3 - 30)
    if collectionView == myfirstCollectionview
    {
        //For FirstCollectionView
        return CGSize.init(width: 90, height: 90)
    }
    else
    {
        //For SeondCollectionView
      return CGSize.init(width: 90, height: 90)
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept an answer to help others.